# How do I solve the "Incompatible Gradle Versions" error after adding the google play-service-location library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-geofence

Running Android Studio V3.4.1, I create a new "Empty Activity" project (accepting defaults) and it compiles and runs fine.  Running Analyze|Inspect_Code generates a few warnings, nothing that seems serious.  I then add the "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0" library to the app (either through the File|Project_Structure menu to by editing the app manifest build.gradle" file).  It still compiles and runs, but "Inspect Code" now generates an "Incompatible Gradle Versions" error.  Specifically, while the project is targeted at SdkVersion 28, two new project-level libraries `com.android.support:support-v4` and `com.android.support:support-media-compat` are both added at `V26.1.0`.

I guess that the `play-service-location:16.0.0` depends on these two new libraries at V26.1.0, but I don't know how to resolve the lint error or even whether I need to?

I couldn't find a way of removing or editing the libraries within Android Studio.  I tried tweaking the `app/app.iml` file to change V26.1.0 to V28.0.0 but this didn't work.

Although I've been doing software development for 30+ years, I am an Android newbie, so I'm not really sure what's going on.

The inspection results state "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include '`com.android.support:animated-vestor-drawable:28.0.0' and 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0'.`
Double-clicking on this error moves the cursor to the app manifest file on a line '`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Android Studio gives an option to suppress the error, but this feel a little like putting my head in the sand...

Updates:
[image: Screenshot added]

Extract from app.iml file:

```
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:documentfile:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:collections:28.0.0@jar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:print:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Gradle: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1@jar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: android.arch.core:common:1.1.1@jar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0@aar" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1@aar" level="project" />
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've edited the original question to add a screen shot and extract from the app.iml file showing the majority of "com.android.support:*:28.0.0" files, but also the two inconsistent "26.1.0" entries.